# How to format a simple Ansible inventory file for amazon ec2 hosts?

Tags: ansible

I am unable to run the example ad hoc command:

```
ansible -m ping hosts --private-key=~/home/ec2-user/ -u ec2-user
```

the error is:

```
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: hosts
[WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do
```

The hostname is: ip-10-200-2-21.us-west-2.compute.internal

I can ping the host from my ansible control node by this hostname.

I created the hosts file with the touch command and it looks like this:

```
ip-10-200-2-21.us-west-2.compute.internal
```

Do I need to include something more? Do I need to save it with a particular extension? Thank You much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run an ad-hoc command you can run a command in the following syntax

```
ansible <HOST_GROUP> -m <MODULE_NAME>
```

This is assuming your inventory file is in /etc/ansible/hosts.  If your inventory file is located in a different spot we can use the command

```
ansible <HOST_GROUP> -m <MODULE_NAME> -i <LOCATION_TO_INVENTORY_FILE>
```

to change the location of the inventory file

Now whats missing is that your inventory file should have a host group in it. Something like:

```
[ec2]
ip-10-200-2-21.us-west-2.compute.internal 
other-ec2-host-that-needs-to-be-pinged.us-west-2.compute.internal
```

The host group is the text inbetween the square brackets [], which in this case is ec2.  Now we can reference all ec2 hosts using the host group of ec2.

To ping all the hosts in the ec2 group (assuming the inventory file is /etc/ansible/hosts) run

```
ansible ec2 -m ping -i /etc/ansible/hosts
```

Comment: Thanks – that worked for the inventory – now I’m getting private key errors instead which is better. My private key file is not in the normal place, it’s in /home/ec2-user
First Ansible erred because it said “permission denied” to this private key, so I set the dir to 777 and now it errors saying permissions are too open
The command I’m running is the one you showed plus reference to private key file:
ansible ec2 -m ping -i /etc/ansible/hosts --private-key=~